# Event on non existing button

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on WPF app and I want to dynamiclly add buttons.
For example I have a loop, which add 5 new buttons.

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Button addButton = new Button();
    addButton.Name = "addButton" + i;
    addButton.Content = "addButton" + i;
    this.devicesButtonStackPanel.Children.Add(addButton);
}
```

Now I have 5 buttons in StackPanel.

I need event on every button.

I'm trying to use this:

```
private void addButton0_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("test");
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You haven't attached the event listener. addButton.MouseDoubleClick += addButton0_MouseDoubleClick;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to bind to the event when you create the button:

```
Button addButton = new Button();
addButton.Name = "addButton" + i;
addButton.Content = "addButton" + i;
// Bind your handler to the MouseDoubleClick event
addButton.MouseDoubleClick += addButton0_MouseDoubleClick;
this.devicesButtonStackPanel.Children.Add(addButton);
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply do it in your code

```
                Button addbutton = new Button();
                addbutton.Click += addButton0_MouseDoubleClick;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just subscribe each button the the handler

```
addButton.Clicked += addButton0_MouseDoubleClick;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not attach your `event handler` to the `MouseDoubleClick event`. Please attach your control event to event handler method as you are showing as:

```
addButton.MouseDoubleClick += addButton0_MouseDoubleClick;
```

Your code should be like as like the below code snippet:

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Button addButton = new Button();
    addButton.Name = "addButton" + i;
    addButton.Content = "addButton" + i;
  //Use the addition assignment operator (+=) to attach your event handler to the event.
    addButton.MouseDoubleClick += addButton0_MouseDoubleClick;
    this.devicesButtonStackPanel.Children.Add(addButton);
}
```

you can do work with these button as below:

```
  private void addButton0_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       string buttonName = ((Button)sender).Name;
       string buttonNumber = buttonName.SubString(0,buttonName.Length -1 );

       switch(buttonNumber)
       {
         case "0":
         // do work for 0
          break;
          case "1":
          // do work for 1
         break;
        } 
    }
```

Refer:
[How to: Subscribe to and Unsubscribe from Events (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx)